# Limit the acceptable range of a value in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, validation, user-defined-types

I want to define a tinyint with an accepted range of 0 - 10. I know how to use triggers to validate a column and achieve this effect.

However, is it possible to create a user-defined data type that specifies this range as a rule? Then, if a value outside of range is attempted, of course an error would be thrown automatically, without the need of triggers?

Comment: sql-server, sql-server-2008 and mysql-triggers???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [CHECK constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188258.aspx) rather than [user defined types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175007.aspx) which are quite awkward to use

Answer (score 3):

First, create a rule with your constraint, then a type, then associate it:

http://www.mssqltips.com/tip.asp?tip=1628

(But I agree with gbn, 99.99% of the time, just use a check constraint)